# Suspicious flood of ARP requests

Tags: arp, wireshark

I'm trying to review a Wireshark capture and it seems the network is heavily flooded with ARP requests that make no sense to me.

1. The destination is not "Broadcast", but some unknown DELL device (none are present on the network).
2. The "who-has" IP is not part of the same network the pc is capturing from.
3. The "tell" IP is not part of the same network either.

[image: ARP requests example]

Any ideas of what could be going on here?

Comment: What/where was this capture taken?

Comment: On a Desktop, connected via Ethernet. Capture has been taken with wireshark.

Comment: Trace down the source of the traffic, and check the system sending them. Looks sorta like what a load balancing device does to verify reachability. I would suspect a misconfigured thing (VM?) before "hackerz!?!" (It could also be a broken DHCP client using the wrong interface.)

Comment: "_I'm not the owner of the network_" Unfortunately, questions about networks you do not directly control are off-topic here.

Comment: The destination Mac aged out of the forwarding tables of the switches between you and the sender.

Answer (score 0):

Likely, someone has connected a rogue device to your network.

You need to look for the *source MAC* address. If that is unknown, check the switch's MAC address table for the source port. Work your way back from there, across your switches, to the port of the source device. Disconnect or shut down the device.

Comment: The source MAC looks suspiciously fake

Comment: The thing is the IP address for the suspicious device literally ends with .230.1 whereas the IP addresses of devices connected to the network all end with .227.XXX. It doesn't look like that IP can be part of the same network.

Comment: Unless you know that IP network address it doesn't really matter. A device can send anything. You need to track the source MAC.

Comment: Source MAC is 00:11:22:33:44:55, which matches the router's one, but is also a commonly spoofed MAC address i guess.

Comment: Pretty weird address for a router - a manual MAC should be LAA instead of UAA... Your router might be trying to ARP that address. Check its routing table and config.

Comment: Are you sure that's the router's MAC?  What kind of router is it?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I'm not the owner of the network. I asked the owner to double check the source MAC, they compared it with the one printed on the back of the router and it does not match. We were convinced it matched since querying the arp table shows that the entry for the default gateway (the forementioned router) is linked to the 00:11:22:33:44:55 MAC address. Very weird situation here.

Comment: Sorry, networks that are not completely under your control are explicitly off-topic here, see the [help]. You might even be hacked and the gateway spoofed.